# Mysql Database select with Python Flask and Templates not reflecting the DB changes

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using a mysql DB with sqlalchemy and myqsl connection. Everything appears to be working fine on the first load of the web page and the select returns everything as it should.

If I manually go into the Mysql DB and change a column value from say OKAY to FAILED then commit the change and I refresh or re-run the Flask template in the browser, the old value persists. If I run a select in DBeaver or via the command line the value has 100% changed. Even if I close the browser down or run an incognito window, the status still stays the same, so the problem appears to be on the flask side somewhere.

It only seems to notice that the value has changed if I bounce the flask environment, but I cannot do this each time something changes in the DB.

Does anyone know why this could be the case?

This is the select query call from an import statement

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, MetaData, Table
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://username:password@localhost:3306/dbname")
metadata = MetaData(bind=None)
table = Table(
'applications',
metadata,
autoload=True,
autoload_with=engine
)
stmt = select([table.columns.id,
           table.columns.name,
           table.columns.description,
           table.columns.overallstatus,
           table.columns.active
          )
connection = engine.connect()
db_application_result = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
connection.close
engine.dispose()
```

The route to the template looks like this

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
from Scripts.db_get import db_application_result

return render_template('test.html',
                       db_application_result=db_application_result)
```

and then the template (shortened looks like this)

```
<table>
{% for row in db_application_result %}
    <tr>
    {% for d in row %}
        <td>{{ d }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

and a select of all the data looks like this. When I change the value of row1 column 5 from FAILED to OKAY and run the select via DBeaver it has changed, but when I refresh (Force refresh) of the Flask template page it remains as FAILED. If I restart the flask app, the data then refreshes.

```
1   App1    Name1 Application   FAILED  TRUE    WLS1    MQ1
2   App2    Name2 Application   OKAY    TRUE    WLS1    MQ2
```

It looks like some sort of DB caching or flask caching, but I cannot seem to work out what is causing it.

I have tried these values in the app.py file

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

and added this to the end of the DB connection just in case.

```
    connection.close
    engine.dispose()
```

Any help or suggestions on this would be awesome as the problem seems like it should not really be an issue but it is :(

I do not think it is with sqlalchemy as I saw the same problem with using **import mysql.connector**

Thank you,

Comment: I notice that if I place the sql call statement inside the @app.router('/test') block the data changes correctly, but when I call it using "from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, MetaData, Table" it does not change? Does this mean that it will only run the import once?

Comment: Yes, imports are imported only once. Make your life simpler by putting all imports at the beginnings of files. If I may have a friendly and well-meant suggestion, learn the basics. Do a python course, do your exercises, from the easiest to more complex.